# Tokenize two strings using nested loops using strtok_s

Tags: c, string

I am trying to tokenize two strings in the nested loops using strtok_s function however i am unable to parse  the complete string separated by the delimeter(;) the code for the same is

```
char* string1Bigrams = "he;el;ll;lo";
char* string2Bigrams = "he;el;ll;lo;ow;ed";
string1Bigram = strtok_s(string1Bigrams,";", &str1Sep);
    while( string1Bigram != NULL )
    {
        string2Bigram = strtok_s(string2Bigrams, ";", &str2Sep);
        while( string2Bigram != NULL ) 
        {
            if(strcmp(string1Bigram, string2Bigram) == 0)
            {
                bigramMatches++;
                break;
            }
            string2Bigram = strtok_s(NULL,";", &str2Sep);
        }
        string1Bigram = strtok_s(NULL,";",&str1Sep);
    }
```

when the loop runs it gives random behaviour. Sometimes getting NULL as a token before the string ended.

Any suggestion, about how this could be done

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

The strtok* family of functions modify the string as they tokenize it, so during the second and later passes through the inner loop, you're tokenizing the string "he" rather than the original string "he;el;ll;lo;ow;ed".

If you want to solve this using the strtok_s function, you've got two options: you can do it in two stages, first tokenizing the strings to generate two lists of bigrams, and then comparing the lists to find matches, or you can tokenize a copy of the second string, restoring the copy from the original after each pass through the inner loop.